# If $E$ and $K$ are splitting fields, then $E\cap K$ is a splitting field for what polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $E$ and $K$ are splitting fields over a field $F$ for some polynomials $f$ and $g$, then the composite $EK$ is the splitting field for $fg$. It is also standard that $E\cap K$ is a splitting field over $F$, but I haven't found any information about for which polynomial (or family of polynomials) $E\cap K$ is a splitting field.

Is there anything known about which polynomial $E\cap K$ is a splitting field for? Is there any relationship to $f$ and $g$ like there is in the composite case?

Comment: Have you tried examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try the above for example with

$$E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;,\;\;K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\;\;\text{over}\;\;\Bbb Q\implies E\cap K=\Bbb Q$$

So the intersection is the splitting field of all the rational linear polynomials.

But if

$$E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2,i)\;,\;\;K=\Bbb Q(i)\;\;\text{over}\;\;\Bbb Q\implies\;E\cap K=K\;\ldots$$

Thus I don't think there's a general rule for this.